# "It must have been .. " or "It must was "?

Tags: modal-verbs, past-tense, present-perfect, past-simple, present-simple

I had a sentence transformation exercise and I had to say that sentence "I'm sure it WAS Tom who cleared everything up." with (It must...) and I wrote "It must was john who cleared up everything" but it's said it's wrong and the correct answer is "It must HAVE BEEN Tom who cleared everything up.". I don't think there's a mistake even if I write "It must BE John who cleared up everything.". So, Am I wrong and why?

Comment: *must was* is ungrammatical. You probably meant to say *it must've been Tom who cleared up everything.* - *must be* indicates certainty in the present, *must have* indicates certainty in the past, that is, when you are sure about something that happened in the past.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. Modal verbs like "must" can only be followed by an infinitival verb phrase. So to transform _I'm sure it was Tom ..._ by using "must", you have to say _It must have been Tom ..._, where "have" is an infinitival verb-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because only a bare infinitive, such as *be* or *have*, can follow a modal verb such as *must*.

The *have* in *must have been John* is a bare infinitive. It is not a conjugated verb. There is no

> *It must *has* been John who...

any more than there is a

> *It must *was* John who...

Both those constructions are wrong, and I marked them with an asterisk (*) to show that they are ungrammatical.